# react-select: how to keep dropdown open when styling in inspector?

Tags: reactjs, npm, components, react-select

I'm using react-select and I'm customizing it,I didn't found an option to do this. Is there some workaround I can use to keep dropdown open when I'm styling it?

Comment: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/927. There might be some useful comments here.

Comment: <Select menuIsOpen={true} ... /> works for me.

Answer (score 192):

In chrome, got to Elements > Event Listeners > open "blur" > with the mouse go to the right of where it is written "document", then you can see a button "Remove" > click on it

Comment: perfect answer, this covers all cases

Comment: with the latest versions you may need to delete the "focusout" event listener instead of blur.

Answer (score 73):

If you're using V2 there's a `menuIsOpen` prop you can use to keep the menu open at all times.

If you're using Chrome and you have the React Developer Tools plugin, you can inspect your component in the React tab of the console and manually toggle this property right from your browser. For V1, you can toggle the `isOpen` state to achieve the same behavior.

Comment: I use menuIsOpen. it worked but when I click on select for change my selected option, It didn't open again.

Answer (score 49):

That's work for me:

```
menuIsOpen={true}
```

Comment: Worked Fine, this should be the right answer

Comment: This is the right answer, but is crypted....

Set the property menuIsOpen to true, by code or if you have the React Developers Tool browser extension , you can set it temporally with this tool

Answer (score 18):

Simple hack goes this way

Run this command on your console open the menu and then wait for 5 seconds and the debugger will automatically be applied and screen will be freezed.

```
setTimeout(() => {debugger;}, 5000)
```

Comment: If using F8 does not work this is second easiest solution. Thanks!

Comment: Used to do this; note however that this may prevent e.g. React Dev Tools from working - removing the blur handler per the top answer works better!

Comment: Nice one, works for me where the other solutions failed. 

Answer (score 9):

Beforehand I exec `window.onkeydown = () => {debugger}` in js console and after expanding the dropdown I click any key

It's important to keep developer tools open

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows 10 Chrome 80+. Dropdown is closed as soon as debugging starts.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `menuIsOpen` props. It was on the react-select documentation and it works!
Docs: https://react-select.com/props
Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

in select component send this as props

```
menuIsOpen={true}
```

Answer (score 4):

2023 answer for Google Chrome:
You can enable "Emulate a focused page" by using `Cmd/Ctrl + Shift + P` in Chrome devtools and that won't blur the document if you use devtools. Very handy for debugging focus styles, focus handler, dialogs, popovers, dropdowns, etc.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this could help:

```
<Select 
   ref={el => (this.selectRef =el)}
   onBlur={() => {
     setTimeout(
       () => 
          this.selectRef.setState({
            menuIsOpen: true,
          }),
        50
     );
   }}
  />
```

Comment: this is the only thing that worked. by the way, you cannot use this inside set timeout that way, you have to create a variable reference outside

Answer (score 2):

By using the [Chrome React extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi), you can force the "isOpen" (v3: "menuIsOpen") state value to true on the Select component.

more info here: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/927#issuecomment-313022873

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Chrome to debug. You can hover over the select drop down and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> simultaneously and it should be automatically selected in the debug window

Answer (score -6):

Open dropdown and then right click on dropdown... it will drown a pop over and on inspector.. now you can work upon your dropdown.

Comment: As soon as you click somewhere in the inspector you will lose the focus.

Comment: This actually won't work, the problem is you cannot perform any action or the menu would disappear