# Style ReactSelect menu to display all options with no vertical scroll

Tags: css, react-select

We currently have a select made in React with ReactSelect that has a fixed 16 options in the table. Currently, when the `control` is clicked, the `menu` appears which shows 11 items and has a vertical scroll to scroll down to show the remaining 5 items.

This would be better if all 16 items showed when `menu` appeared, with no vertical scroll. We have tried to create the following custom style:

```
    menu: (provided) => ({
        ...provided,
        background: '#DDDDDD',
        marginTop: '-1px',
        zIndex: 10,
        height: // what to put here? we've tried "auto", "fit-content", "100%" and none are good...
    }),
```

is there another element in the `select` (other than `menu`) that we should be styling, or is there a better way to style the menu such that all options show?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, I used the most upvoted answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49299042/react-select-how-to-keep-dropdown-open-when-styling-in-inspector) to inspect the ReactSelect menu (which I wasn't able to do previously). I discovered that `menuList` has a default `maxHeight` of 300px, which was preventing the menu from growing larger.

This then did the trick for me:

```
menuList: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    maxHeight: null
}),
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks so much